# Place inner Element outside of a "max-width"-Container

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to set an element (red), which is placed in a container with a centered max-width (gray) on 50% of the viewport-width.

Code is like:

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:700px;margin:0 auto;">
<div class="inner-element">Should be 50% of viewport-width</div>
</div>
```

[image: gray: Container, Red:Div placed outher Container]

I tried with position:absolute but maybe there is a better solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `vw` like below

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:grey;
  padding:20px 0;
}

.inner-element {
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  width:50vw;
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="">
  <div class="inner-element">Should be 50% of viewport-width</div>
</div>
```